# Using a for loop or cast to create a list

Tags: arrays, list, powershell

I was researching ways to convert an `Array` to a `List` collection and the answer suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743476/powershell-convert-string-to-liststring) used casting.

In my script, I constructed a `List<string>` with a for loop like this:

```
$backup_details = Get-Content "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\source.txt"

$backupItems = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]

foreach($item in $backup_details){
    $backupItems.Add($item)
}
```

Is there any reason why I should use casting over this method?

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the first place? What problem are you trying to solve by using a generic list instead of an array?

Comment: I want to remove the first item and `arrays` don't support `RemoveAt()` or `Remove` without casting to a `List`

Comment: For that reasoning, instead of converting to a list, I'd recommend using ArrayList instead.

Comment: @Nick - Using the `for` loop method like I've shown or casting? that's my real question.

Comment: why the downvote? I did my research and even linked to it! I asked a question because I wasn't sure if casting is the correct way to go

Comment: Removing the first element of an array the PoSh way: `$a = 1, 2, 3; $b, $a = $a`.

Comment: If you really want to use a collection something like this should work just fine: `[Collections.ArrayList]$backupItems = Get-Content ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like you are over complicating things in the pursuit of your goal. As mentioned, you can simply rebuild the array without the first item, or move that item to a different variable.

Remove the item entirely:

```
$backupItems = $backup_details | Select -Skip 1
```

(or you could pipe `Get-Content` to `Select -Skip 1` initially and skip that step, or even do `$backup_details = $backup_details | Select -Skip 1` to redefine itself)

Move the first item to a different variable, in case you want to keep it for later.

```
$firstItem, $backupItems = $backup_details
```

And, (courtesy of Nick's comment, because I didn't think of it), you could just cast it as an ArrayList when you import the data:

```
[Collections.ArrayList]$backupItems = Get-Content "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\source.txt"
$BackupItems.RemoveAt(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't understand the down vote though. I researched before asking, and I even tried before posting.

Comment: @srosemond I doubt there's anything to understand. Sometimes people will just randomly downvote questions or answers. If it's just a single downvote and the person who cast it is unwilling to give a reason: just ignore it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I don't know who down voted you, but I intend to up vote the question just to balance out the internet karma. Sometimes people are having an off day and they're overly critical and down vote when they probably shouldn't.  If it makes you feel better I've been down voted myself on a few answers, not because the answer is wrong or doesn't work, just because somebody preferred a different approach.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - Thanks :D